# Resizing a UIButton programmatically by maintaining a margin

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm adding a UIButton to a tableView footer programmatically. This button has a left and right margin that is equal to the tableView margin:

```
UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 300, 34);
deleteButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
```

I'm adding autoresizingMask because I want to support rotation. However, it does not work as I want, as the button stretches all the way down to the right, as shown by the image below.

Any idea how to fix it? If I remove the autosizing property then the margin is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` resizes the view (and all its subviews) returned by `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`. To fix your issue, you need a wrapper view that layouts your `UIButton` without using autoresizing. Here’s an example implementation of such an `UIView` class:

```
@interface ButtonWrapperView : UIView {
    UIButton *_button;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *button;

@end


@implementation ButtonWrapperView

@synthesize button = _button;

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero])) {
        _button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
        [self addSubview:_button];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Layout button
    _button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.width - 20.0f, self.bounds.size.height);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_button release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Simply return this view in `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` and your button should be displayed properly.

I’ve also [uploaded a sample project](http://mtths.me/3q2B) which completely implements the above solution.

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks! I'm going to try this later and get back to you.