# UItableview Separator line's height

Tags: ios, uitableview, list-separator

Can I adjust the height of the `UITableview`'s separator line? I add `UIView` at the cell to use as separator line and its good, the problem is that when I slide the cell to delete it, the delete button is the problem, its overlapping the separator line, or can I adjust the delete button's height?

[image: separator line][image: delete]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't resize the delete button, resize your bottom `UIView` so it can overlap the delete button.

Answer (score 1):

The code pasted in by Rashad is pretty old (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228932/custom-size-of-uitableviewcells-delete-button)) and doesn't seem to work for iOS 7 or iOS 8.

Here is updated code that works:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {

    UIView *deleteButtonView = nil;

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        // find the delete view in iOS 8
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]){
            deleteButtonView = subview;
            break;
        }

        // find the delete view in iOS 7
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"]) {
            for (UIView *secondSubview in [subview subviews]) {
                if ([NSStringFromClass([secondSubview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) {
                    deleteButtonView = secondSubview;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int heightOffset = 5;
    CGRect buttonFrame = deleteButtonView.frame;
    buttonFrame.origin.y = heightOffset;
    buttonFrame.size.height = self.frame.size.height-2*heightOffset;
    deleteButtonView.frame = buttonFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always draw separator line like a subView on contentView of cell. And disable separatorStyle in tableView. And customise delete button like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22396248/887325

Answer (score 0):

In you TableViewCell `layoutSubviews` method write this:

```
if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) {
    UIView *deleteButtonView = (UIView *)[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    CGRect newf = deleteButtonView.frame;
    newf.origin.x = 250;
    newf.origin.y = 47;
    newf.size.width = 30;
    newf.size.height = 50;

    deleteButtonView.frame = newf;
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl is missing in ios 11